# How to skip compile errors in Maven

Tags: java, maven, class, build, compilation

Now we're using Maven to build the java programs from git repository, and there's a big repository that contains more than 20,000 java class files.

If compile errors happened during the building, the Maven build job will stop and not generate any class files or jar files. For this we tried to comment out individual class files by using  tag in pom.xml file, but then other compile errors happened cause the class files which referring to the commented out class files could not pass.

We want to **find a "auto-skip" option/function in Maven** so that we can build the programs, only generate compile passed class files normally even there are some compile errors, then we can check the all compile errors in log file later. But so far we didn't find it.

It would be appreciate if anyone could share ideas or advise for this issue.

Many thanks.

Comment: "skip compile errors"? Do you understand what compile errors are? You can't skip compile errors. Just correct your code so it'll compile.

Comment: have you tried `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Comment: @ZahidKhan That will simply not solve compile errors. It will skip to run tests. Apart from that it is not necessary to do `install`. Compile errors means your code is syntactically/semantically not correct. This has to be fixed.

Comment: @ZahidKhan that skips the execution of tests, not compile errors

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you.
Since we're using Maven and Jenkins to deploy the programs to verification environment for execution test, it would be best if our team could run the compile passed cases in verification environment and research/modify the compile error cases in local environment by referring build logs at the same time.

Comment: @Allen.Chen There is no such thing as "compile passed cases". Either your code compiles, or it doesn't. You can work with modules, and compile them separately, but still, if you want to run all your tests, you'll still need to fix your issues. If there is a dependency between the code you want to test (even if that compiles) and the part that doesn't compile, you'll still need to compile it, otherwise, you risk testing an old (no longer used) version of the code, meaning your test would be pointless

Answer (score 1):

There are two options in maven:

`-fae`, `--fail-at-end`

`-fn`, `--fail-never`

You can use them in the following way:

`mvn --fail-never clean compile` - to get and ignore compile errors

`mvn --fail-at-end clean compile` - to get compile errors and fail at the end.